# Find elements inside object arrays in MongoDB document collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Nodejs backend with MongoDB to hold my object structures with Mongoose as the ORM.

I have a work order object which is following the below pattern. There are thousands of generated work orders and I have a requirement to find the work orders assigned to a given worker on a given date.

Could you help me to come up with a find query?

The query details

1. Should be able to query and find itenary - allocated work order - details for a given worker in a given date
2. Need to use `allocatedWorker` (worker) and `allocatedDateTime` (date and time) to match and find

`Work order` object

```
{
    customer:       String,
    address:        String,
    /**
     * List of to do items. Each item will mainly belong in to a given category
     * and a collection of tasks.
     * The task can be system generated, admin assigned or customer raised.
     */
    todo: [
        {
            category: String,

            /**
             * A collection of raised tasks
             */
            tasks: [
                {
                    /**
                     * Holds the customer request details
                     */
                    request: {
                        workItem:           String,
                        instructions:       String,

                        /**
                         * Preferred date and time
                         */
                        dateTime:           String,
                        /**
                         * Preferred worker if any
                         */
                        preferredWorker:    String,
                        receivedDateTime:   String
                    },

                    /**
                     * Details of the schedule
                     */
                    schedule: [
                        {
                            /**
                             * Allocated worker's user name
                             */
                            allocatedWorker:    String,
                            allocatedDateTime:  String,
                            allocatedDuration:  Number,
                            /**
                             * Schedule changed date and time
                             */
                            scheduledOn:        String,
                            /**
                             * Scheduler's user name
                             */
                            scheduledBy:        String,
                            /**
                             * Scheduled task status
                             *  0: Pending - new
                             *  1: Scheduled - allocated
                             *  2: Work In Progress
                             *  3: Completed
                             *  4: Overdue
                             */
                            itemStatus:         Number
                        }
                    ],

                    /**
                     * Stage of the work order
                     *  0: Pending - new
                     *  1: Scheduled - allocated
                     *  2: Work In Progress
                     *  3: Completed
                     *  4: Overdue
                     */
                    status:                 Number
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried, `Workorder.find({$and:[{'todo.tasks.schedule.allocatedWorker': worker}, {'todo.tasks.schedule.allocatedDateTime': day}]}, function(err, orders) {})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query:

```
Workorder.find({'todo.tasks.schedule.allocatedWorker'‌​: worker, 
'todo.tasks.schedule.allocatedDateTime': day}, function(err, orders) {});
```

Remember that both will do exact value match(exact name and dateTime) stored in db.